# How do I get AwesomeWM to switch to a tag?

Tags: awesome-wm

I currently have a rule so Iron opens on my 'www' tag, but how do I get Awesome to switch to that tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can click on the `www` tag in the tag list (see `man awesome` and search for `bindings`), or you can take a look at these `LUA` functions if you want to do more (e.g. to set a shortcut for it):

- [awful.tag.viewidx](http://awesome.naquadah.org/doc/api/modules/awful.tag.html#viewidx)
- [awful.tag.viewonly](http://awesome.naquadah.org/doc/api/modules/awful.tag.html#viewonly)

Or if you want to switch to a tag once a rule is applied you can use this form:

```
{ rule = { class = "Iron" } ,
  properties = { tag = tags[1][3] , switchtotag = true } }
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific as I want to incorporate a command into the rule:


"{ rule = { class = "Iron" }, properties = { tag = tags[1][3] }}"

Comment: I 'fixed' it by adding a function into the menu to focus onto the tag them spawn Iron. Should do seeing as I'll only open it from the menu.

Comment: Ok, now I understand what you want (I edited my answer).

Answer (score 2):

Added this to rc.lua before the menu:

```
function load_prog(cmd, tag)
   awful.tag.viewonly(tags[1][tag])
   awful.util.spawn(cmd)
end
```

And then in the menu:

```
{ "Iron", function () load_prog("iron", 3) end }
```